# How to switch between Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, 20.04

Both were installed on the same disk. Ubuntu 20.04 is on sda5, Ubuntu 18.04 is on sda7. When I rebooted, it appeared that the installation is failed so I tried another time to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside with Ubuntu 20.04 but there was one on sda7. So how to know if it is working?

Comment: Why do you need 18.04 alongside 20.04? (I ask, because maybe there are better options depending on what you want).

Comment: Regarding your question, probably you need manual partitioning during installation (a.k.a. "*Someting else ...*")

Comment: @pLumo I need ROS Melodic

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960105/unable-to-install-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-20-04. If you need Melodic only, I would suggest you install Ubuntu 18.04 in a Qemu/KVM virtual machine.

Comment: Have a look at installed LXD via snap and then you can spin up a 18.04 version of linux as a container but using the same kernel.
e.g.{
snap install lxd

lxd init --auto

lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 ubuntu18

lxc exec ubuntu18 bash}